# bad_alloc exception with vectors in c++

Tags: c++, vector, bad-alloc

I'm not very expert in programming with c++ so my question may appear a bit stupid, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I want to allocate a vector with the instruction

```
vector <short int> myvec(rowotot * coltot)
```

in order to represent a matrix.

Before proceeding, I want to verify if I have sufficient space to allocate my vector.
If I use

```
try { 
    vector <short int> myvec(rowtot * coltot);
}
catch (bad_alloc& ba) {
    cert << "ERROR: ";
    cerr << ba.what() << endl;
}
```

and then I try to modify the elements of the vector, I can't because

> myvec is not declared in this scope

How can I do the check on the memory before saving any value in the vector?
I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Just do everything you need to do in the `try` block. Note: I've seen this question before. I'm looking for duplicates.

Answer (score 9):

A simple solution is to declare the vector outside to the try block and then use [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to allocate the space in a try-catch block.

```
std::vector<short int> myvec;
try
{
    myvec.reserve(rowotot*coltot);
}
catch (const bad_alloc& ba) 
{
    cerr <<"ERROR: ";
    cerr << ba.what() << endl;
}
```

This puts the vector in the outer scope but allows the allocation to be catch-able.

If you need to have the vector with `rowotot*coltot` elements already in it then you could use the same thing but either call [`std::vector::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) to create the items or create a temporary vector and assign it to `myvec`.

```
std::vector<short int> myvec;
try
{
    myvec.resize(rowotot*coltot);
    // or
    myvec = std::vector<short int>(rowotot*coltot);
}
catch (const bad_alloc& ba) 
{
    cerr <<"ERROR: ";
    cerr << ba.what() << endl;
}
```

I also change `catch (bad_alloc& ba)` to `catch (const bad_alloc& ba)` as it is preferred to catch by `const &`

Comment: Or maybe reassign it in the try block, like: `myvec = std::vector<short int>(rowotot*coltot)`, so that it already contains the items. Otherwise you rely on the assumption that outside the try block not more than `rowotot*coltot` items will be added and it won't need to reallocate.